# Porting u-boot-2020.04 to a EVB board, but spi nand flash(GD5F2GQ5xExxG) is not working

Tags: u-boot, dm

problem description:

1. designware-spi controller embedded in SOC
2. spi nor flash(MX25U25635F) on evb CAN works well.
3. spi nand flash(GD5F2GQ5xExxG) on evb is not working,
   when entering command "**nand device** or **nand info**", u-boot returns "**no devices available**"

my effort:

```
**dtsi snippet:**
    spi0: spi@80000000 {
        compatible = "snps,dw-ssi";
        reg = <0x0 0x80000000 0x0 0x1000>;
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <0>;
        clocks =  <&sysclk>;
        clock-names = "baudclk";
        status = "okay";
        spi_nand@1 {
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <1>;
            compatible = "spi-nand";
            spi-cpha = <1>;
            spi-cpol = <1>;
            spi-tx-bus-width = <1>;
            spi-rx-bus-width = <1>;
            reg = <1>;
            spi-max-frequency = <50000000>;
        };
    };
```

xxx_defconfig:

```
CONFIG_CMD_BIND=y
CONFIG_CMD_DM=y
CONFIG_CMD_GPT=y
CONFIG_CMD_MTD=y
CONFIG_CMD_NAND=y
CONFIG_CMD_NAND_TRIMFFS=y
CONFIG_CMD_NAND_LOCK_UNLOCK=y
CONFIG_CMD_NAND_TORTURE=y
CONFIG_DM_MTD=y
CONFIG_MTD_RAW_NAND=y
CONFIG_MTD_SPI_NAND=y
CONFIG_SPI=y
CONFIG_DM_SPI=y
```

xxx_common.h

```
...
#define CONFIG_SYS_NAND_SELF_INIT
...
```

drivers\mtd\nand\raw\nand.c

```
void nand_init(void)
{
...
#ifdef CONFIG_SYS_NAND_SELF_INIT
    board_nand_init();
#else
    ...
#endif
}
```

Only config spi controller's related register in function `board_nand_init( )`,
I want to call `spinand_probe()` in this function, but I don't know how to do it.
Can somebody help me? I am a newbie to u-boot. Thanks

Comment: add debug info in `spinand_probe( )`, but no print info output during u-boot booting sequence. I think this function cannot be called.

Comment: update：add below code `struct udevice *dev; uclass_get_device(UCLASS_MTD, 0, &dev); device_probe(&dev);` in fucntion board_nand_init(void), I found spinand_probe() can be called, but some error seemingly occurs in  device_probe(&dev). Dedbugging...

Comment: update : `device_probe(&dev)` error, should be `device_probe(dev)`

Comment: should add below procedure: `struct mtd_info *mtd;` `dev_get_uclass_priv(dev);`  `nand_regiter(0, mtd);`